# Clustering vernemq docker containers running on different machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mqtt-vernemq

I was hoping this would be an easy one by just using the below snippet on the second instance's `docker-compose.yml` file

```
- DOCKER_VERNEMQ_DISCOVERY_NODE=<ip address of the first instance>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Log of the second instance confirms it's attempting to cluster:

```
13:56:09.795 [info] Sent join request to: 'VerneMQ@<ip address of the first instance>'
13:56:16.800 [info] Unable to connect to 'VerneMQ@<ip address of the first instance>'
```

While the log of the first instance does not show anything at all.

From within the second instance I can confirm that the endpoint is accessible:

```
$ docker exec -it vernemq /bin/sh
$ curl <ip address of the first instance>:44053
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

then in the log of the first instance I see an error which is totally expected and confirms I've reached the first instance

```
13:58:33.572 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.3050.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in vmq_cluster_com:process_bytes/3 line 142
13:58:33.572 [error] Ranch listener {{172,19,0,2},44053} terminated with reason: bad argument in vmq_cluster_com:process_bytes/3 line 142
```

It might have to do with the fact that ip address as seen from within the docker container is `172.19.0.2` while the external one is `10. ...`.

Also tried adding hostname of the first instance to `known_hosts` to no avail.

Please advise.

I'm using erlio/docker-vernemq:1.10.0

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.27.2, build 18f557f9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this sorted by creating a [docker overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/)

on machine1: `docker swarm init`
on machine2: `docker swarm join --token ...`
on machine1: `docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable vernemq-overlay-net`

The relevant bits of my dockerfile are:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  vernemq:
    container_name: ${NODE_NAME:?Node name not specified}
    image: vernemq/vernemq:1.10.4.1
    environment:
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_NODENAME=${NODE_NAME:?Node name not specified}
      - DOCKER_VERNEMQ_DISCOVERY_NODE=${DISCOVERY_NODE:-}

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: vernemq-overlay-net
```

with the following env vars:

machine1:

- NODE_NAME=vernemq1.example.com
- DISCOVERY_NODE=

machine2:

- NODE_NAME=vernemq2.example.com
- DISCOVERY_NODE=vernemq1.example.com

**Note:**
Chances are machine2 won't find `vernemq-overlay-net` due to a bug in docker-compose as far as I remember.
In that case you start a container with docker: `docker run -dit --name alpine --net=vernemq-overlay-net alpine` which will make it available for docker-compose.